# Opentelemetry + Kibana, some JVM metricks appear at Kibana´s tab but other doesn´t

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metrics, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

Problem:
At JMV it shows: No data to display, but it should.

Hello SO,
some metrics related to JVM doesn´t appear me using Kibana (7.17) + Elastic. The only that shows is **Thread Count** but I want all the others: **CPU usage, System memory usage, etc.**

Considerations:
Maybe is related to things like this "process.runtime.jvm.memory.usage renamed to jvm.memory.used" but, how can I see the measure that the openagent 2.0.0 is sending to kibana? And also how can I know the name that kibana´s expect?

Context:
I read the readme: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Configuration:
Kibana: 7.17
jar: lib/opentelemetry-javaagent-2.0.0.jar
Server: Wildfly26
Protocol:
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.protocol=grpc

Here is an screenshot:
[image]

Also adding the option:
**otel.metrics.exporter=logging**

y see in the log jvm.cpu.recent_utilization so the problem is probably in Kibana´s side

So a new question is:
Why I can´t see jvm.memory.used or jvm.cpu.recent_utilization.

There are the rest of the measures:
[image]